# how create objects through iteration

Tags: javascript, loops

What if I want more than 3 objects? can I loop it somehow?

```js
let newArr = []

let newObj1 = {};  let newObj2 = {};  let newObj3 = {};

newArr.push(newObj1);
newArr.push(newObj2);
newArr.push(newObj3);

console.log(newArr);
```

If I add 3rd loop my array will brake, how I can substitude it?
it is my full code:

> let arr = [
>       {fullName : {surname : 'xxx', firstName : 'yyy', middleName: 'zzz'}}, 
>       {fullName : {surname : 'XXX', firstName : 'YYY', middleName: 'ZZZ'}} ] let boolObj = {fullName : {surname : true, firstName : true,
>   middleName: false}} let loc = {"fullName.surname" : "Прізвище",
>   "fullName.middleName" : "По-батькові"}
>
> let newArr = [] newObj1 = {}; newObj2 = {}; newObj3 = {};
>
> for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
>       let arrObjKeys = Object.keys(arr[i]);
>       let arrObjObjKeys = Object.keys(Object.values(arr[i])[0]);
>       let arrObjObjValues = Object.values(Object.values(arr[i])[0]);
>       let boolObjValues = Object.values(Object.values(boolObj)[0]);
>       let locObjKeys = Object.keys(loc);
>       let boolObjStr1 = `${Object.keys(arr[i])}.${arrObjObjKeys[0]}`;
>       let boolObjStr3 = `${Object.keys(arr[i])}.${arrObjObjKeys[2]}`;
>       let ojbStr1 = `value${i+1}`
>       if(boolObjStr1 === locObjKeys[0] && arrObjObjValues[0] !== '') {
>           newObj1.name = loc[boolObjStr1];
>           newObj3.name = loc[boolObjStr3];
>           newObj2.name = arrObjObjKeys[1];
>       }
>       for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
>           if(boolObjValues[0] === true) {
>               newObj1[ojbStr1] = arr[i][arrObjKeys][arrObjObjKeys[j-2]];
>           }
>           if(boolObjValues[1] === true) {
>               newObj2[ojbStr1] = arr[i][arrObjKeys][arrObjObjKeys[j-1]];
>           }
>           if(boolObjValues[2] === true) {
>               newObj3[ojbStr1] = arr[i][arrObjKeys][arrObjObjKeys[j]];
>           }
>       } } newArr.push(newObj1); newArr.push(newObj2); newArr.push(newObj3);
>
> console.log(newArr);

In future to my arr I want to add object for example:

> let arr = [
>       {fullName : {surname : 'xxx', firstName : 'yyy', middleName: 'zzz', data : {xxx: 'Boom'}}}
>   ]

after these such code as

> newObj1 = {}; newObj2 = {}; newObj3 = {};
>   becomes bad solution?

But if I iterate through my

> newObj1 = {}; newObj2 = {}; newObj3 = {};

it will be 3 loops and my code will be broken.
Pls tell how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, you can. `arr=[];for(let i =0;i <10;i++) arr.push(new Object());`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a rather general/basic question, but why not try a simply for loop?

```
let  arr = [];

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  const object = new Object();
  arr.push(object);
}
```

Comment: Why invoke the constructor with `new Object()`?

Comment: Sure, there are definitely a few other ways of creating new objects, and they are well documented in many blog posts. Listing them all here would have been an overkill to a duplicated question. I am simply typing the easiest example. For the OP's benefit, do check this out! https://codeburst.io/various-ways-to-create-javascript-object-9563c6887a47

Comment: The easiest example would be to use an object literal instead. `const object = {};` or even `arr.push({})` alone

Comment: You are absolutely right.